How to determine If a matrix can equal itself to the $n$-th power but not to a certain $i, 2\le i\le n$?
I encountered the following question in my text book: if   matrix $A$  set of eigenvalues is $\{1,0\}$
does $A$ have to be equal to $A^2$ ?
I know that if a  diagonal matrix if equal to itself to the nth power so is any matrix similar to it   so if there exists a basis of eigenvectors so that the matrix we have is made up of Eigen values 1 0  then it would be true ,we did not learn how to proof two matrices not being similar if an Eigen  basis does not exist
I tried to search for any matrix that is not similar to a matrix that's in the first category so I took\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
and  compared It with this
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
they are clearly not similar since $\det(A_1-In)$ is different from the second $\det(A_2-In)$
and it worked ,is this how this kind of question is usually approached or is there a way  to think of a counter example more intuitively ?
I also tried to see if I can think of a a matrix thats equal to itself to the third power but not to the second power  ,
$$ A^3 = A , A^3 - A = 0,A(A^2 - I_n) = 0,A(A - I_n)(A + I_n) = 0$$
so I deduced A can equal itself to the third power only if eigenvalues are either (1,0,-1) if I don't want it to equal to the second power it should have -1 so I took -In and any matrix similar to it as a solution , how would you approach such questions like A=A^4 but not A=A^2 can this exist and so on

Have a look at matrices which represent rotations.

What about $A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\ 0&0\end{bmatrix}$?

I assumed them wanting both elements that are in the set at least

I see rotation  as in reflection  matrices having a number of eigenvalues but not enough to be similar to a diagonal matrix @badjohn

I was concentrating on the question in the title.  Rotation matrices answer that.  I don't follow the extra restrictions that you want.  Do you want an example that is not similar to a diagonal matrix?  Does it need to be invertible?

I want see what's an approach that can be taken to find counter examples for such questions in general when I can verify its true for diagonal matrices but finding a counter example may not be as clear ,since we did not learn how to prove if a matrix does not have a similar matrix , we just learnt how to disprove a matrix being similar to a certain matrix given  and only if both are diagonlizable

If eigenvalues of $2\times 2$ matrix are $0$ and $1$, then the characteristic polynomial is $x=x^2$, so $A=A^2$. The result is not even true if both of the eigenvalues are same. If you increase the dimension you can find lot of counter examples . Think of possible characteristic polynomials. For example, if matrix has a minimal polynomial $x^n(x-1)=0$. If $A^n=A$, then $x(x-1)=0$ will be a minimal polynomial. A contradicton.

how do you change between characteristic polynomial and matrix representation  , is there an explanation for how to do this?

Is it just saying lets say we have 1 eigenvalue 1 and the rest zeros this would give the polynomial you suggested

This is Cayley-Hamilton theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem): a matrix satisfy its characteristic polynomial.
